# How to omit _prep_q_encoding for e-mail subject in CodeIgniter Email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I faced a strange problem today. I am using Codeigniter Framework, when sending e-mails. Sometimes if the e-mail subject is long, the word breaks. For example, my subject is:

```
This is a notification form test
```

but in the sent mail it shows like:

```
This is a notification form t est
```

As you can see `test` is now `t est`. I searched and found this function:

```
private function _prep_q_encoding($str, $from = FALSE)
    {
        $str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('', ''), $str);

        // Line length must not exceed 76 characters, so we adjust for
        // a space, 7 extra characters =??Q??=, and the charset that we will add to each line
        $limit = 75 - 7 - strlen($this->charset);

        // these special characters must be converted too
        $convert = array('_', '=', '?');

        if ($from === TRUE)
        {
            $convert[] = ',';
            $convert[] = ';';
        }

        $output = '';
        $temp = '';

        for ($i = 0, $length = strlen($str); $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            // Grab the next character
            $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
            $ascii = ord($char);

            // convert ALL non-printable ASCII characters and our specials
            if ($ascii < 32 OR $ascii > 126 OR in_array($char, $convert))
            {
                $char = '='.dechex($ascii);
            }

            // handle regular spaces a bit more compactly than =20
            if ($ascii == 32)
            {
                $char = '_';
            }

            // If we're at the character limit, add the line to the output,
            // reset our temp variable, and keep on chuggin'
            if ((strlen($temp) + strlen($char)) >= $limit)
            {
                $output .= $temp.$this->crlf;
                $temp = '';
            }

            // Add the character to our temporary line
            $temp .= $char;
        }

        $str = $output.$temp;

        // wrap each line with the shebang, charset, and transfer encoding
        // the preceding space on successive lines is required for header "folding"
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/^(.*)$/m', ' =?'.$this->charset.'?Q?$1?=', $str));

        return $str;
    }
```

calling from

```
public function subject($subject)
{
    $subject = $this->_prep_q_encoding($subject);
    $this->_set_header('Subject', $subject);
    return $this;
}
```

In the first function it says:

```
// Line length must not exceed 76 characters
```

so that was the problem. How can I add longer length subjects for e-mail, without editing the base functions? What is the best way to support longer length subjects without breaking the words? Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I also work in codeigniter but I never used codeigniter Email class. PHPmailer works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your config for email write : **`$config['wrapchars'] = 100;`** to increase the limit, also  write : **`$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;`** to wrap words. Hope it helps.

Comment: Post your email initialization code above please. @KanishkaPanamaldeniya